# Probability for choosing a number iteratively and at once

Tags: probability, statistics

I have been posed the following question:

We have a list of $n$ numbers (WLOG say $1$ to $n$) and we are choosing $m$ numbers out of it **according to a given fixed probability weightage.**

Case 1: We choose the $m$ numbers from the list at the same time.

Case 2: We choose the $m$ numbers iteratively, updating the probability weightage after each iteration.

Now if we repeat case 2 enough number of times and compare the number of times a particular number has been chosen, would the probability of getting that number match its probability of case 1?

My approach: I was trying it out for the case when the probabilities are all the same ($1/n$) and the probability of getting a number picked seems to match that of the first case. But I don't have any idea how to approach this problem for a general weight distribution.

Comment: Think of numbers as labeling balls in a box, when you draw balls from the box do you put them back before the next draw? In other words, can the same number be chosen more than once? And how do you update the "probability weightage"?

Comment: You normalize the probabilities after each iteration so that they add upto 1

Comment: You mean like, for numbers 1,2,3 with weights 1/2,1/3,1/6, the first time we take number 1 out, then the weights for 2 and 3 becomes 2/3 and 1/3 resp.? Then how do you take weighted numbers at once? Like in the same example, you are suggesting the "pair weight" of (1,2) is 1/6, that of (1,3) is 1/12, that of (2,3) is 1/18, then normalize the three again?